# Sonarqube analysis only on last commit

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, cicd

We are using sonarqube for code quality checks in CI/CD pipeline using jenkins. I am scanning my code and performing Quality gate checks. Based on success or failure the pipeline proceeds or stops. I would like to check quality gate status for new code in last commit and not entire scan result.   How can I achieve this in pipeline? Any suggestion?

Comment: Based on your comment to @George. You are looking for functionality that is at the core of Sonarqube. You have new code definitions where you can define what is seen as new code. Just have a feature branch analysed and it will show the new code compared to the refernece branch

https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.6/project-administration/defining-new-code/#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20a%20global,the%20default%20for%20your%20projects.&text=You%20can%20set%20a%20new,at%20Project%20Settings%20%3E%20New%20Code.

Answer (score 1):

if am i correct you mean you need analysis your source code real time with any push from developer right?

if you need something like this you have to use hook script in Git and change hook script there. with any push from developers you have to  put the source code in temporary branch according to hash commit of push request in Git then for analysis you need to call Sonarqube job in hook script and send temporary branch name as parameter to Sonarqube job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Sonarqube, but if you don't pass the complete codebase, including the new modifications made, it would count as an entirely "new project."

In order to provide an accurate picture of the tendency of the metrics being defined in your QG, Sonar must evaluate the codebase as a whole.

Having said that, some metrics, like code coverage, can be set up in your QG to only apply to new code.

Comment: yes, that is what exactly I am looking for. How can I apply qualitygate only to new code that is added since my last commit?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SonarQube does **not** support "new code" definition as one would naturally expect, i.e. the last commit. First you need to understand the [definition of "new code"](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/clean-as-you-code-settings/defining-new-code/).

You have two options:

1. **Previous version** - however here you need to increase the version number in `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` file, which is not what you do always you. If you have a rule that you increase the version number with each commit, this is the option for you.
2. **Number of days**: Defines new code as any code that has changed in the last X days (max 90).

For projects where we do not increase the version number upon each commit, we came with a workaround which is good enough and close to what we expect from the "new code = last commit" notion. And it is to **set the new code as Number of days = 1**:
[image]